# TS: Mongoose Union Type of two Models: findOne Signatures incompatible

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-generics, mongoose-schema, union-types

This is about a type error in Typescript.

I have two Mongoose Models with different types of documents. They share some properties and I want to be able to use `findOne` on the union type of both Models. I am told the two function signatures are incompatible by Typescript.

I am dealing with two collections. All documents that share a collection have the same fields. Between collections, the documents share some of their properties. General things like `createdAt` and `_id` but also more specific things. However, they also differ in a few key ways, which is why I separated them in the first place.

I now have two Mongoose Models for these two collections. Let's call them `ModelA` and `ModelB`. Inside a function, I have some code where it doesn't matter which of the two collections I am dealing with. The function could look like this:

```
async function foo(model: ModelA | ModelB, query: any) {
    const res = await model.findOne(query);
    console.log(res);
}
```

The above code underlines `findOne` with the error:

```
Each member of the union type 
'{ <ResultDoc = Document<unknown, any, InterfaceA> & InterfaceA & { _id: ObjectId; }>(filter?:
FilterQuery<InterfaceA>, projection?: ProjectionType<InterfaceA>, options?: QueryOptions<...>, 
callback?: Callback<...>): Query<...>; <ResultDoc = Document<...> & ... 1 more ... 
& { ...; }>(filter?: FilterQuery<...>, projection?: Projectio...' 
has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Looking at the signature I see that, indeed,

- ModelA.findOne expects `filter?: mongoose.FilterQuery<InterfaceA>` as it's first parameter and
- ModelB.findOne expects `filter?: mongoose.FilterQuery<InterfaceB>`.

I don't care about these differences though and hoped that Typescript would just figure out that they're basically the same and union them. I just want compatible functions I can call and get something along the lines of `Document<InterfaceA> | Document<InterfaceB>` as `res`.

What would be a simple solution to achieve this? Is there a way to do it without having to resort to wrapping this in an extra function each time?

Comment: Would be nice if you had a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q), so that I don't have to figure out how to reproduce the problem myself.